# Показ notification - ошибок нет, но уведомление не отображается

Tags: java, android, уведомления, android-notification

Есть сервис который каждую минуту должен посылать notification. Но данный код почему то не срабатывает.

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
    tabSpec.setIndicator(" List ");
    tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, ListActivity.class));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
    tabSpec.setIndicator(" CheckBox ");
    tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, CheckBoxActivity.class));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    NotificationService.start(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

```
public class NotificationService extends IntentService {

public NotificationService() {
    super("NotificationService");
}

private static final String START_SEND_NOTIFICATION = "start_send_notification";
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private NotificationManager notificationManager;


// method for start service
public static void start(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    intent.setAction(START_SEND_NOTIFICATION);
    context.startService(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case START_SEND_NOTIFICATION:
                showNotification();
                    runnable.run();
                break;
        }
    }
}


private  int counter = 0;

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Conunt: " + counter);
        counter++;
        if (counter>60){
            showNotification();
            counter = 0;
        }

        handler.postDelayed(this, 710);

        //handler.removeCallbacks(this);

    }
};

private void showNotification() {
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    System.out.println("<<Showing notification>>");

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setTicker("New notification")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
//                    .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText("Hello")
            .setProgress(100,20,true);

    Notification notification = builder.build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;


    notificationManager.notify(1,notification);
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".activities.ListActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".activities.CheckBoxActivity"/>

    <service android:name=".service.NotificationService"/>

</application>
```

Comment: Добавьте манифест в вопрос.

Comment: А под "код не срабатывает" вы имеете в виду крах приложения с ошибкой? или всё работает, сервис запускается, приложение не останавливается, метод `showNotification` вызывается, но уведомления нема?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, все работает. Приложение не падает, метод showNotification отрабатывает, но Notification не всплывает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16448278/3212712) проблема может быть в отсутствии иконки у уведомления. Поробуйте её добавить:

```
builder.setTicker("New notification")
.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
.setContentText("Hello")
.setProgress(100,20,true)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

---

Также советую отказаться от `TabActivity`, коя является устаревшей аж с `API 13`

И от класса `Notification` тоже. Используйте лучше `NotificationCompat`.

Comment: Добавил .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher); и заработало. А что можно вместо TabActivity использовать?

Comment: @KirillStoianov, в идеале, вам надо подключить `support-library`, использовать `AppCompatActivity` и сделать там табы с помощью `TabLayout` из `support-design` либы.